# How to get process id of a command

Tags: shell, background-process

We are running some command in batch mode. We need to do some more tasks once the existing command is done, so we need to wait until this command is done.

For example:

```
bsub -q gui -I calibre -drc -batch
wait
```

Can you please tell how we can get the process id of this job mentioned in the wait command or some other alternative to wait until existing command terminates?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
bsub -q gui -I calibre -drc -batch & pid=$!
wait ${pid}
```

Here `pid` is a variable. You can name it anything.

Answer (score 0):

The builtin [wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296863/what-is-the-difference-between-wait-and-sleep) command should already do the trick - it should wait, until `bsub` is finished, although `bsub` will run in the background. But if you don't want to use `wait`, you can get the PID with e.g. `pgrep bsub` or `ps -eo pid,comm | grep bsub` and then you can write your own "wait-until-finished` routine.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried upper command pid=$!  wait ${pid} but we are getting error

"wait too many arguments"

Please look into it and give solution if possible .

Thanks 
Yisha

Answer (score 0):

We have tried upper command this also pgrep bsub and then wait pgrep bsub  still we are getting error

"wait too many arguments"

Please look into it and give solution if possible .

Thanks Yisha